# Ошибка "No CUDA GPUs are available" при работе с библиотекой detectron2

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Работаю с библиотекой `detectron2`, нейросеть всегда обучаю в `colab`. Начал выдавать ошибку:

> No CUDA GPUs are available

Раньше такого не было. С помощью проверки ядра `cuda(torch.cuda.is_available())` выдаёт `False`, при этом `!nvcc --version`  выдаёт `cu116`.

Как исправить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка "`No CUDA GPUs are available`" обычно возникает, когда у вас нет доступной GPU или CUDA не настроен правильно.

Если вы используете Google Colab, убедитесь, что вы выбрали правильную среду выполнения, которая поддерживает GPU. Чтобы проверить, выберите пункт меню "Среда выполнения" ("Runtime") и убедитесь, что "Сменить среду выполнения" ("Change runtime type") указан на "GPU".

Если вы уверены, что используете правильную среду выполнения, попробуйте перезагрузить среду выполнения, чтобы убедиться, что все компоненты правильно настроены. Вы можете перезагрузить среду выполнения, выбрав пункт меню "Среда выполнения" ("Runtime") и выбрав "Перезапустить среду выполнения" ("Restart runtime").

Если проблема сохраняется, убедитесь, что у вас установлена версия CUDA, которая совместима с вашей версией PyTorch и Detectron2. Попробуйте переустановить CUDA, используя версию, которая соответствует вашей версии PyTorch и Detectron2.

Также проверьте, что ваша GPU настроена правильно и доступна в системе. Попробуйте выполнить команду "nvidia-smi" в терминале и убедитесь, что ваша GPU отображается в списке.

Наконец, если ничего не помогает, попробуйте переустановить PyTorch и Detectron2, используя последние версии библиотек. Вы можете установить их, используя команду pip:

```
pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111 torchvision==0.11.1+cu111 torchaudio==0.10.0+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html

pip install detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu111/torch1.10/index.html
```